# Go lang Google Sheets api Pivot table

Tags: go, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

first of all sorry my bad eng
I wrote such a code, but I don't know how to request it, can you help me?

```
pivotTable := &sheets.PivotTable{
        Source: &sheets.GridRange{
            SheetId:          inSheetId,
            StartRowIndex:    0,
            StartColumnIndex: 0,
            EndRowIndex:      10,
            EndColumnIndex:   4,
        },
        Rows: []*sheets.PivotGroup{
            &sheets.PivotGroup{
                SourceColumnOffset: 1,
                SortOrder:          "",
                ShowTotals:         true,
            },
        },
        Columns: []*sheets.PivotGroup{
            &sheets.PivotGroup{
                SourceColumnOffset: 1,
                SortOrder:          "",
                ShowTotals:         true,
            },
        },
        Values: []*sheets.PivotValue{
            &sheets.PivotValue{
                SummarizeFunction:  "SUM",
                SourceColumnOffset: 3,
            },
        },
        ValueLayout: "HORIZONTAL",
    }
    request := sheets.PivotTable(*pivotTable)
```

how do i make a debug request from here?

Comment: I cannot connect the code example with the question. Your question is tagged `google-sheets-api`, and its title also refers to Google Sheets. Does this all mean you want to make an HTTP request to Google Sheets web API to "upload" the document you have created using the cited piece of code?